# cannot input chars in password field

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

When I'm trying to log into 99design I can enter the username, but when I type into the password field nothing happens. This happens only on one computer with Windows 7 and only on Chrome (37.0.2062.103 m)

I've reinstalled Chrome and cleaned up any remains of the previous installation folder. In Firefox, Opera on this computer I can login. Other computers with Chrome are Ok.

Any idea how to fix this?

Here are some captions from the PC that the login works:
[image: ok]

and here I can't

[image: not ok]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the **Disable DirectWrite** from the **chrome://flags** worked for me

thanks Ramhound for the [previous answer](https://superuser.com/questions/807840/facebook-fonts-messed-up)